# How to prove the proposition about minimization?

Tags: linear-algebra

$~$
Hi,

Supposed that $A \in \mathbb R^{n{\times}n}$ is a symmetric positive definite and $V$ is a subspace in $R^{n}$, then $x_{\ast}{\in}V$ is the solution of 
$$\min\limits_{x{\in}V}\|z-x\|_{A}$$
if and only if $$A(z-x_{\ast}){\perp}V.$$ 
Please note that $\min\limits_{x{\in}V}\|z-x\|_{A} = \|A^{\frac{1}{2}}(z-x)\|_{2}$.

Is there anyone who can help me for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = {1 \over 2}\langle x-z, A(x-z) \rangle$, then
${\partial f(x) \over \partial x} = (x-z)^T A$.

Suppose $x_* \in V$ is the minimiser and that there is some $v \in V$ such that $\langle A(x_*-z), v \rangle < 0$ and let $\phi(t) = f(x_*+tv)$, then $\phi'(0) = {\partial f(x_*) \over \partial x} v = \langle A(x_*-z), v \rangle < 0$ which contradicts $x_*$ being a minimiser.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. In my exercise, the problem is the generalization of a particular case $A = I$ (unit matrix). The particular case can be proved as follows. The subspace $V$ determines an unique orthogonal projection $P$. So $\|z-x\|_{I}^{2} = \|z-x\|_{2}^{2} = \|\left(I-P\right)z+Pz-x\|=\|\left(I-P\right)z\|_{2}^{2}+\|Pz-x\|_{2}^{2}{\ge}\|\left(I-P\right)z\|_{2}^{2}$, where the equality in the last step holds if and only if $x = Pz$. Denoting $x_{\ast} = Pz$, I can obtain $\left(z-x_{\ast}\right){\perp}V$. This particular case may be a cue for the generalized one on the top.

Answer (score 0):

By positive definiteness, the space is direct sum of $V$ and $W=\{\, x\mid \forall v\in V:\langle v,Ax\rangle=0\,\}$, and the norm squared of any vector is the sum of the norms squared of its components in $V$ and $W$. Now the condition $x\in V$ forces $z-x$ to have the same component in $W$ as$~z$, and its component in $V$ can be chosen at will; its norm will be minimal if the latter is zero, which means $z-x\in W$, as claimed.